# User does not have role after adding it - Cancancan & Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, cancancan, rolify

I am using Rails 5 with Cancancan and Rolify. When I add a role to a user it will show up in their list of roles, but will return false when calling has_role?.

Example from the console.

```
user = User.first 
user.roles # => []
user.add_role :admin 
user.has_role? :admin #=> false (what?!)
user.roles #=> [id: 1, name: "admin....
```

Any help here would be really appreciated. Not sure why this does not work. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you reload the user after adding the role? `user.add_role :admin; user.reload;  user.has_role? :admin`

Comment: why your `roles` return an array like this? `[id: 1, name: "admin...`? it should be array of multiple `role` objects, is it a typo or association error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `has_role?`.
`has_role?` is just a helper method which is used in rails applications.
`has_role?` has this definition:

```
def has_role?(role)
    current_user && current_user.has_role?(role)
end
```

which can be added to your application helper.
You can call this method in your .erb or .rb file like this:

```
<% if has_role?(:admin) %>
```

or:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
```